# Use Prometheus and Go to grab Govee Data

Tags: macos, go, github, terminal, prometheus

**My end goal is to be able to hook up to a Govee Smart Plug+ via bluetooth and grab the usage data so that I can populate a google sheet.**

I believe it should possible to do as I found this Github repository that sounds like something similar to what I need to do. -> https://github.com/jdoupe/govee-exporter/

I'm a complete newbie to Prometheus and Go as this is the first I've heard of them while trying to work with the above repository, so please bare with my naiveness. :)

Here's what I have done so far.

1. Downloaded the Github repository to my MAC (placed it under my User folder on my computer)
2. Installed the Go library via Terminal inside the govee-exporter folder
3. Downloaded and installed Prometheus via their site -> https://prometheus.io/ *(Not sure if I needed to do this as I see some of the Prometheus packages are imported via the main.go file inside the repository)*
4. Started Prometheus up and can successfully access the localhost:9090/graph

Inside Terminal I navigate to my govee-exporter folder and enter `go build .` and I get the following error

```
main.go:15:2: no required module provides package github.com/jdoupe/govee-exporter/internal/collector; to add it:
    go get github.com/jdoupe/govee-exporter/internal/collector
main.go:16:2: no required module provides package github.com/jdoupe/govee-exporter/internal/config; to add it:
    go get github.com/jdoupe/govee-exporter/internal/config
main.go:17:2: no required module provides package github.com/jdoupe/govee-exporter/internal/updater; to add it:
    go get github.com/jdoupe/govee-exporter/internal/updater
```

So then I run `go get github.com/jdoupe/govee-exporter/internal/collector` but get another error back

```
go: github.com/jdoupe/govee-exporter@v0.0.0-20200918015329-3a09a1c143f1 (matching github.com/jdoupe/govee-exporter/internal/collector@upgrade) requires github.com/jdoupe/govee-exporter@v0.0.0-20200918015329-3a09a1c143f1: parsing go.mod:
    module declares its path as: github.com/xperimental/flowercare-exporter
            but was required as: github.com/jdoupe/govee-exporter
```

And likewise for the other two folders that the main.go file is trying to import. So I went over to the go.mod file and replaced `github.com/xperimental/flowercare-exporter` with `github.com/jdoupe/govee-exporter`
Then I run `go build .` which appears to build and then I run `go run main.go` and I get the following message

```
# github.com/jdoupe/govee-exporter/internal/updater
internal/updater/updater.go:15:2: "github.com/jdoupe/govee-exporter/pkg/govee" imported as miflora and not used
internal/updater/updater.go:24:8: undefined: govee
internal/updater/updater.go:77:47: undefined: govee
internal/updater/updater.go:83:10: undefined: govee
internal/updater/updater.go:87:10: undefined: govee
internal/updater/updater.go:191:15: undefined: govee
# github.com/jdoupe/govee-exporter/internal/collector
internal/collector/collector.go:9:2: "github.com/jdoupe/govee-exporter/pkg/govee" imported as miflora and not used
internal/collector/collector.go:63:41: undefined: govee
internal/collector/collector.go:113:68: undefined: govee
```

Inside the config.go file I noticed the listenAddr wasn't the same as where my Prometheus metrics were coming from, so I adjusted it to match mine which is 9090.

**Where do I go from here to connect to my Govee plugs?** I've got their mac addresses and device type, but I don't know where to enter that information.

Comment: [`govee-exporter`](https://github.com/jdoupe/govee-exporter/) is very old (4 years) and does **not** build (as you've seen). You can (1) revise `go.mod` to be `module github.com/jdoupe/govee-exporter` and (2) revise `pkg/govee/goovee.go` to be `package govee` in order for `go build .` to succeed.

Comment: You will need to get `govee-exporter` working (see next comment) before you can configure it to be "scraped" (have the metrics read) by Prometheus. `govee-exporter` publishes (Prometheus) metrics on `:9294` (by default). When `govee-exporter` is running, try to read the metrics by `curl http://localhost:9294/metrics`. Proceed once this returns results.

Comment: Prometheus requires a [configuration](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/) that defines `targets` to be "scraped" (have their metrics read from them). Conventionally, one target is the Prometheus server itself. You will want to add `govee-exporter` as a second target. For convenience, I'll add an example configuration (assuming `govee-exporter` is working and publishing to port `9242`) below.

Answer (score 1):

[`govee-exporter`](https://github.com/jdoupe/govee-exporter/) is very old (4 years) and does not build (as you've seen).

To get it to build, you can:

1. revise `go.mod` to be `module github.com/jdoupe/govee-exporter`; and
2. revise `pkg/govee/goovee.go` to be `package govee`

You should be able to run it as `go run .`

You will need to get `govee-exporter` working before you can configure it to be "scraped" (have the metrics read) by Prometheus.

`govee-exporter` publishes (Prometheus) metrics on `:9294` (by default). When `govee-exporter` is running, try to read the metrics by:

```bash
curl http://localhost:9294/metrics
```

Proceed once this returns results.

Prometheus requires a [configuration](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/) that defines targets to be "scraped" (have their metrics read from them). Conventionally, one target is the Prometheus server itself. You will want to add `govee-exporter` as a second target.

Here's an example `prometheus.yml`:

`prometheus.yml`:

```
global: nil

scrape_configs:
  # Prometheus
  - job_name: "prometheus-server"
    static_configs:
      - targets:
          - "localhost:9090"

  # Govee Exporter
  - job_name: "govee-exporter"
    static_configs:
      - targets:
          - "localhost:9242"
```

Then run Prometheus using this config:

```bash
prometheus \
--config.file=prometheus.yml
```

All being well, you should then see `govee-exporter` added as [`targets`](http://localhost:9090/targets)

And you should be able to query `govee-exporter` for the metrics it exports using Prometheus' [graph](http://localhost:9290/graph) tab.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the information! I've got the Go running better now, but since I'm running the macOS system it's now erroring out on finding the Bluetooth Device: hci0. 
`INFO Bluetooth Device: hci0  FATA Error creating device: can't init hci: only available on linux `
Do you have any knowledge of what I'd need to put in there instead? Thank you

Comment: I don't. I don't use macOS